# Using cluster of eGPUs crashes Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia

We've set up an AMD Ryzen computer with Ubuntu 21.10, and plugged 6 Akitio Duo machines each with 2x NVIDIA 4GB cards, as well as a 13th card directly on the PCIe slot which is a 16GB NVIDIA card (RTX A4000).

We have this rig running 16x threads of Alphafold2 (https://github.com/deepmind/alphafold#running-alphafold) and for the most of it, it can run without issues for a while.

But every once in a while, maybe once every 24hr or so on average, the computer completely locks up. If we only have 4x Alphafold2 running on the 16GB card, the computer is stable for weeks, so the issue seems to be with the jobs on the Akitio eGPU cards.

Is there anywhere that can tell us why it's crashing (the computer is on, but completely unresponsive, only a physical power button reboot does the trick)?

Looking at `/var/log/kern.log` doesn't seem to show anything indicative of the issue.

EDIT:

Running `dmidecode` when only the 16GB card plus 2 Akitios are plugged, gives the following:

```
# dmidecode --type 9 | egrep "Usage|Type|Designation"
        Designation: PCIEX16_1
        Type: x16 PCI Express
        Current Usage: Available
        Designation: PCIEX16_2
        Type: x8 PCI Express
        Current Usage: In Use
        Designation: PCIEX1_1
        Type: x1 PCI Express
        Current Usage: Available
```

thanks @matigo for the suggestion to look at syslog. In the latest crash, it shows the bit above the '@^' bit, then the hard reboot was at 10:02.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that points to the issue? 

Comment: Added a screenshot of the before/after of the last crash. The green bit in the middle makes me think it was a serious crash, adding these binary characters between the crash and the reboot. The machine is connected via Ethernet, so NetworkManager shouldn't be having issues with the wireless as the wireless isn't needed to be connected to the network...

Comment: By any chance you're using a shared file system such as `OCFS2` or `GFS2`?

Comment: NFS, yes, mounted like `mount -t nfs url:/this /that`.